# Post to a users facebook wall and to a Pages wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I'm looking to have a "like" button on my site that when pressed will post to the users Facebook wall and also to a Facebook pages wall.

So the like would appear on the Pages wall with "user xzy likes this"

Anybody know how I can implement this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can react to a like event by subscribing to the like button, but this will only post to a session users wall, in the react you can however compose a new post that can be posted by user to page wall.

1. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ 
   you will need JS-SDK first.
2. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
   you will next need to subscribe to any like events on your page.
3. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/
   you can use the feed dialog to generate the post to page.

> **NOTE:**  to post to a page you will need a page access token appended to
>   the post request.